# How to Create rule data in html

Tags: javascript, html

Create page htm include number 0~9 and rule, when you click to number or rule then data change the same image 
[image]

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like the html range-type input, e.g. `<input type="range" id="mySlider" min="0" value="5" max="9" step="1">`. For example, see [this description](http://thenewcode.com/757/Playing-With-The-HTML5-range-Slider-Input).